# Changing iphone orientation, then changing it back cuts my view in half?

Tags: iphone

I have a view controller in my iphone app setup so that when I change the orientation from portrait to landscape, I change the view. When I change the orientation back from landscape to portrait, the initial view comes back, except this time it is all crammed into the left hand side of the screen. Eventually, when I change orientations enough times everything disappears completely. Is this a common issue beginners have? What could I be doing wrong?

In my root controller I am allowing the orientation to change only when a specific view is being shown with this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
if (self.currentView == (NSInteger*)Chart || self.currentView == (NSInteger*)Detail) {
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
```

Where `self.currentView` is an enum of what view I currently have up. The Detail view I want to make sure stays as a portrait view, but when I change the orientation while on that view I want it to change the view to the Graph. Again, this works fine the first time, but when I change back from Graph to Detail, it crams all the controls on the Detail view to the left hand side of the screen.

Here is how I'm changing the view:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{

if (self.currentView == (NSInteger*)Detail && (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)) {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"changeView" object:self userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:Chart] forKey:@"view"]];
}

if (self.currentView == (NSInteger*)Chart && (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)) {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"changeView" object:self userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:Detail] forKey:@"view"]];
}
```

Comment: How are you handling the rotations? Are you programmatically changing anything? Can you post the code?

Comment: I added code to show how I'm changing the view with the rotation. In my root controller I'm removing the view that is there then adding the new one with `[self.view addSubView:newView]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@justin I once did this which got me into same situation as you are. May be you can check if you haven't done something like this

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    CGRect rect;
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        rect = CGRectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x,tableView.frame.origin.y,
                                 tableView.frame.size.width - 50, tableView.frame.size.height - 30);        
    }
    else {
        rect = CGRectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x,aBar.frame.origin.y,
                          tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.frame.size.height);     
    }
    [tableView setFrame:rect];
    return YES;
}
```

All I wanted was a table view with small frame in Portrait mode, without saving the original Frame I was trying to reduce its width and height which eventually brought the table view to a very small size after multiple rotation..

Lolzzz. I should have first saved the original tableview frame and then done something like this

```
if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
    tableView.frame = CGRectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x,tableView.frame.origin.y,
                      tableView.frame.size.width - 50, tableView.frame.size.height - 30);       
}
else {
    tableView.frame = originalTableViewFrame;
}
```

Comment: I'm not doing anything with the frame when I'm changing orientations, I'm just adding and removing views from the root controller's subview. Do I need to reset frame sizes? I wouldn't think I would have to do that if I'm just swapping out stuff in the subview.

Comment: Did you notice that you are using  if (self.currentView == (NSInteger*)Chart || self.currentView == (NSInteger*)Detail) where in (NSInteger*) is not required simply comapre self.currentView == Chart or self.currentView == [Chart intValue]

Comment: Thank you for that. I'm new to Objective C and iPhone dev and appreciate the tip.

Comment: In case you are removing a view from its superview you must set its(the view you removed) frame again before adding this view to any other view (it can the same superview from which you removed earlier) try to use NSLog(@"The frame is %@",NSStringFromCGRect(urView.Frame)); before adding it to any view.

Comment: We are getting closer! I am trying to just set the frame manually to see if I can get it consistent and it is, but still wrong. At least it is consistently wrong. It look right the first time still, but when I change the orientation and change it back it still is wrong, but it no longer disappears. I'll try your samples more specifically next.

Answer (score 0):

check if you have autoresizeSubviews ON (in XIB/Inteface Builder) on your view and possibly parent views and try to turn it off if you are changing frame manually , this solved it for my case